# jquery boolean check to see which are selected

Tags: jquery, boolean

I have 4 checkboxes that uses a boolean to check to see which have been selected. The issue I am having is that I am trying to see if two of these boxes have been checked. If so, show an alert. So if .tb1 and .tb3 show alert inpatient. If .tb2 and .tb3, alert "outpatient" and at its default, display "default".

```js
gateStatus();

var Inpatient = false;
var Outpatient = false;
var contract = false;
    
function gateStatus(){
    
if(Inpatient == true && contract == true){
    alert("In patient gate open");
} else if (Outpatient === false && contract == true) {
    
alert("Outpatient gate Open");
}   
else{
alert("default");
}

    
 $("#result1").on("click", ".tb1", function(){
 var Inpatient = true;
gateStatus();
 }
 $("#result1").on("click", ".tb2", function(){
 var Outpatient = true;
gateStatus();
 }
                  
                  
 $("#result2").on("click", ".tb3", function(){
var contract= false;
gateStatus();
       
  }      
                  
  $("#result2").on("click", ".tb4", function(){
var contract= false;
gateStatus();
       
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="1" class="tb2"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Outpatient<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb1"  name="1"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Inpatient<br><br></div>
</div>

<div id="result2">
   <input type="checkbox" class="tb4" />&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br><input type="checkbox"class="tb3" />&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br><br></div><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Errors, missing `)` of every `on(`

Comment: using `var` statement each time, you are redefining variable to handler local scope

Comment: Is there a reason you keeping a boolean instead of checking is(':checked') or this.checked off of the elements?  I ask because not only are you introducing another variable you have to keep track of, but the logic currently doesn't look like it accounts for if the user clicks a checkbox and then clicks it again.

Comment: the is checked isnt working for me,(I am guessing because I actually have them nested in a bootstrap accordion and I cant reach them that way.  The boolean was almost working and I prefer to go in that route.

Answer (score 0):

Us this instead...?

```
function gateStatus()
{
    if($('.tb1').is(':checked') && $('.tb3').is(':checked'))
        console.log('inpatient');

    else if($('.tb2').is(':checked') && $('.tb4').is(':checked'))
        console.log('outpatient');
}

$(".tb1, .tb2, .tb3, .tb4").on("change", function(){
    gateStatus();
));
```

Comment: why wouldn't this line work `if($("#result2 .tb4").is(":checked") &&  $("#result1 .tb1").is(":checked"))'

Comment: It works as one at at time, but not both.. Am I mssing a bracket?

Comment: What do you mean by "It works as one at at time, but not both"?

Comment: if I do   if($("#result2 .tb4").is(":checked")     It will dislay the message in the console, but not if the other check box is being checked too